# How do I implement a large exponentiation? (As in RSA for example)

Tags: math, rsa, computer-science

I am somewhat familiar with the math behind asymmetric encryption.
I understand how keys are generated and that they can then be used to en-/decrypt data by using the key as an exponent to the data.
Now this is pretty simple to do with comedically small numbers (i.e. `pr = 3`, `pub = 7`, `mod = 22`, `msg = 4`).

- `pow(4,7) % 22` to encrypt to message: `16`
- `pow(16, 3) % 22` to decrypt to original msg: `4`

Let's say I want to encrypt a string or even a file.

I do not understand how I can implement such a ridiculously large exponentiation.

As I understand, I would have to calculate the files' raw binary content by the power of the key, resulting in a bigger blob.
How does one implement such an operation?

Comment: (1) RSA encryption (which is not the only type of asymmetric encryption) can only handle a few hundred bytes of data, and is very slow to boot, so it is generally combined with symmetric encryption as [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) (2) to efficiently compute modular exponentiation with RSA-size numbers [see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) (3) RSA modulus must be the product of (usually two) ODD primes, and thus must be odd

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 : To add to your point (3) - the mathematical part works just fine with an even modulus (for the OP's example of `22`, you can easily check that encrypt + decrypt roundtrips as  expected in both directions) - all that's required is that the two primes used are distinct (or if you're using multiprime RSA, that the modulus is squarefree). Obviously making one of your primes equal to `2` isn't so good cryptographically, but then that's true of any small prime - `2` isn't special there.